# Cursor and while loop in the same procedure sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

first let me explain my schema
simply a doctor write a prescription for a patient
every prescription have multiple drugs each drug has a frequency (Taken every X hour)
and also has a start and end
i have added [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68992f/2) of my tables

my requirement is loop through the table and for every  prescription
create a report (Stored Procedure)

ex patient 1 has drug 1 every 6 hours for 2 days from 20-11-2021 20:00

```
Patient  Drug    Dose 
1          1      1 / 20-11-2021 20:00 (Dose Number / Dose Datetime)
1          1      2 / 21-11-2021 02:00  (Add 6 hour to get next dose)
1          1      3 / 21-11-2021 08:00 
1          1      4 / 21-11-2021 14:00
```

this is my sample query

```
DECLARE @minDate datetime , @MaxDate datetime,
  @CurrDate datetime,@index int,@hour int 
SELECT @minDate = min(startdate),
       @MaxDate = max(EndDate) ,
       @hour=max(Frequency.HourValue)  
FROM Prescription_Detail
inner join Frequency on Prescription_Detail.FreqID = Frequency.Id 
WHERE Prescription_Detail.Id = 1

set @CurrDate = @minDate
set @index = 1

while @CurrDate <= @MaxDate
begin
    PRINT CONVERT(varchar, @index) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CurrDate)
    set @CurrDate = DATEADD(HOUR, @hour, cast(@CurrDate as datetime))
    set @index = @index + 1
end
```

as Per the first comment i will be more specefic 
first table Patients
second table Prescription (one to one with patient)
third table prescription detail (detail for table prescription )
this table has the drug and its start date(date field) start time (time field) end Date, end time , frequencyID (one to one with table frequency)
fourth table frequency has the number of hours
My requirement to for every drug based on start date and time and frequency and end date and time

calculate number of dosage and the time for every dosage 
I have updated Fiddler 
Thank You

the Accepted Solution is based on Numbers table see this [Link](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) for Details

Comment: Your fiddle does not match your query, also please define better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you i have updated both the question and the fiddler

Comment: Your `fiddle` still does not matches with the query posted in question.  Also based on the sample data that you have provided, what is the expected result ?

Comment: the Fiddle has the data and my sample query i know i need cursor which i could not do this is where i need help this sample query take min start date from the whole table i need start date to be specific for each Prescription detail the query i only a trial

Comment: Basic good whitespace and formatting wouldn't go amiss...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need cursor or while loop. All you need is a `number / tally` table.

You can use permanent one or dynamically create one using `recursive cte`. The query below uses a permanent number table

the `cross apply` is to calculate the `StartDateTime` from the `StartDate` and `StartTime` to simplified further calculation

From the `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` together with the dose frequency you can calculate the total number of dose required

```
select p.id, d.DrugID, 
       Dose_No = n.n + 1,       
       Dose_DateTime = dateadd(hour, n * f.HourValue, dt.StartDateTime)
from   Patient p
       inner join Prescription r on r.PatientID = p.id
       inner join Prescription_Detail d on d.PrescriptionID = r.id
       inner join Frequency f on d.FreqID = f.id
       cross apply
       (
           select StartDateTime = cast(d.StartDate as datetime) + cast(d.StartTime as datetime),
                  EndDateTime   = cast(d.EndDate as datetime) + cast(d.EndTime as datetime),
                  TotalDoses    = datediff(hour, dt.StartDateTime, dt.EndDateTime) / f.HourValue
       ) dt
       inner join number n on n.n <= dt.TotalDoses
order by p.id, d.DrugId, Dose_no
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5e473/12)

Comment: thank you for the answer but i need some explanation first why i use the number table    
 n <= datediff(hour, dt.StartDateTime, dt.EndDateTime) / f.HourValue instead i can use    dt.EndDateTime<=dateadd( dt.StartDateTime,hour)   second i need the dose count to reset with every drug not with patient

Comment: Reset Count with both Patient and drug meaning Patient 1 Drug 1 Dose 1,2,3 Patient 1 Drug 2 Dose 1,2,3

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment it is reset with drug and patient

Comment: `datediff(hour, dt.StartDateTime, dt.EndDateTime) / f.HourValue` this will gives you total no of doses. If you use `dt.EndDateTime<=dateadd( dt.StartDateTime,hour) ` you need to consider the `HourValue`. It is not every hour but every 8 hourly for example

Comment: one more thing please how can i get total no of doses i.e Dose No = 1/3 , 2/3 , 3/3

Comment: Total no of doses is `datediff(hour, dt.StartDateTime, dt.EndDateTime) / f.HourValue` . You can calculate this in the `CROSS APPLY`. Updated the query